# ChartWrapper is not displaying the graph

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I'm using the google-chart-api to draw a graph using ChartWrapper class and ControlWrapper class. Here is the code I have been using.

This is the function to load hard-coded data.

```
   function drawVisualization() {
    // Prepare the data
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['TimeLine', 'Time-Option', 'LOC', 'Comments'],
      ['Monthly', '1', 200, 20],
      ['Monthly', '2', 300, 30],
      ['Weekly', '1', 150, 15],
      ['Weekly', '3', 35, 3],
      ['Daily', '1', 230, 23],
      ['Daily', '2', 178, 17],

    ]);
```

This is my ControlWrapper.

```
     var timelinePicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
      'containerId': 'control',
      'options': {
        'filterColumnLabel': 'Timeline',
        'ui': {
          'labelStacking': 'vertical',
          'allowTyping': false,
          'allowMultiple': false
        }
      }
    });
```

And this is my ChartWrapper.

```
        var lineChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'LineChart',
        'containerId': 'chart',
        'options': {
          'width': 900,
          'height': 500,
          'chartArea': {top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0}
        },

        'view': {'columns': [1, 2]}
      });

   new google.visualization.DashBoard(document.getElementById('chart')).bind(timelinePicker, lineChart).draw(data);
}
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

And to view the graph,

```
  <body>
  <div id="chart">
  <table>
    <tr style='vertical-align: top'>
      <td style='width: 300px; font-size: 0.9em;'>
        <div id="control"></div>
      </td>
      <td style='width: 600px'>
        <div style="float: left;" id="chart"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
  </body>
```

But still, I don't get any output. Any idea what has gone wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strong suggestion: always try to debug your own code first. There are oh-so-many careless mistakes in there that could be easily caught if you used firebug or the like to catch errors.

### Error #1: DashBoard -> Dashboard

Wrong: `new google.visualization.DashBoard(document.getElementById('chart')).bind(timelinePicker, lineChart).draw(data);`

Right: 
new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('chart')).bind(timelinePicker, lineChart).draw(data);`

### Error #2: TimeLine -> Timeline

Wrong: `'filterColumnLabel': 'Timeline',`

Right: `'filterColumnLabel': 'TimeLine',`

### Error #3: chart -> dashboard

Wrong: `new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('chart')).bind(timelinePicker, lineChart).draw(data);`

Right: `new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard')).bind(timelinePicker, lineChart).draw(data);`

Correct the HTML as well (you have two divs with the 'chart' id):

```
  <body>
  <div id="dashboard">
  <table>
    <tr style='vertical-align: top'>
      <td style='width: 300px; font-size: 0.9em;'>
        <div id="control"></div>
      </td>
      <td style='width: 600px'>
        <div style="float: left;" id="chart"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
  </body>
```

### Final Working Version

```
<!--
You are free to copy and use this sample in accordance with the terms of the
Apache license (http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html)
-->

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>
      Google Visualization API Sample
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['controls']});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function drawVisualization() {
        // Prepare the data
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['TimeLine', 'Time-Option', 'LOC', 'Comments'],
          ['Monthly', '1', 200, 20],
          ['Monthly', '2', 300, 30],
          ['Weekly', '1', 150, 15],
          ['Weekly', '3', 35, 3],
          ['Daily', '1', 230, 23],
          ['Daily', '2', 178, 17],  
        ]);

        var timelinePicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
          'containerId': 'control',
          'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'TimeLine',
            'ui': {
              'labelStacking': 'vertical',
              'allowTyping': false,
              'allowMultiple': false
            }
          }
        });

        var lineChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'LineChart',
          'containerId': 'chart',
          'options': {
            'width': 900,
            'height': 500,
            'chartArea': {top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0}
          },

          'view': {'columns': [1, 2]}
        });

        new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard')).bind(timelinePicker, lineChart).draw(data);
      }

      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <div id="dashboard">
      <table>
        <tr style='vertical-align: top'>
          <td style='width: 300px; font-size: 0.9em;'>
            <div id="control"></div>
          </td>
          <td style='width: 600px'>
            <div style="float: left;" id="chart"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Guess I have done some silly mistakes. Really appreciate your work. The code is working perfectly fine.

Comment: We all make mistakes (I make a lot, which is why I'm so quick at finding them!). They key is to learn how to check first yourself since it's the quickest and easiest way to get the work done.

Comment: Yes. That's true. I'm still new to this IT industry. So I guess, with the time, I'll learn everything step by step.

Comment: The first step is to learn how to use [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) and to debug your own program. If you use [Google Playground](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#categoryfilter_control) to fiddle around with code, it has a debug feature with firebug (which is what I used to debug your code above). At any rate, give it an honest shot and you'll learn a whole lot more. Plus you'll be more self-dependent. Which is always good.